# god is irrelevant?

Tags: logic

I have this argument that god isn't relevant kind of along the lines of Epicurus'.

Obviously it's impossible to prove anything doesn't exist but here is the next best thing in my opinion.

Imagine 2 people. Their actions are for all intents and purposes, the same. They live good lives, helping out when they can. They pay their taxes. They stop at stop signs. They don't cause any unnecessary anguish and just want to be good citizens. The first does this because they believe in god and want to go to heaven. The second doesn't believe in god and just wants to leave the world a little better than it would be without them. It can't be, if there is any justice, that the first has a better chance of getting into heaven. They are, if anything, acting more selfishly than the second person. But the second person did exactly the same as the first person so it's not like they're any more qualified either. It stands to reason that motivations of people have no bearing on a person's worthiness or goodness.

But imagine a child. They, in their innocence, decide that they'd love to help out mum by giving her smartphone a bath. It's beyond repair. Again, nobody is going to argue that a child who is trying to do a nice thing and ends up doing more harm than good is any less good than one that has played football or watched TV or anything else innocuous. It stands to reason that actions of people have no bearing on a person's worthiness or goodness either.

Therefore, in this world, it doesn't matter what you do or think (or say, I'm sure you would find that a similar example will exist). You are just as good as you are. Hence, god is irrelevant.

Any thoughts on the above? Any philosophical sinkholes I'm missing?

Comment: You assume that God exists, and you ask for the effect he causes on the world. So, the question is equivalent to asking _Does God have moving parts?_. Strictly the answer to "is god relevant?" is YES: it was enough relevant for you to ask a question. By asking if his relevance has an effect on the world, you are essentially asking if he exists.

Answer (score 1):

One major issue is the absence of a definition of who or what god is. Without knowing what god's abilities, qualities and motivations are, there is no way of knowing/guessing what is/might be relevant to that god.

The fact you are 'as good as you are' does not in any way prove god is irrelevant. A god may be concerned with any number of things other than whether a person is good or not, and/or may be very concerned with how good you are.

A god may intervene in a person's life, punishing and/or rewarding them in undetectable ways, precisely because of how good or bad a person is.

Even *if* we exist in a world without free will - in which no-one bears moral responsibility for their actions - there is nothing to say that god is not the ultimate agent responsible the ways in which events unfold. In such a circumstance, a person might not be *aware* of god's relevance, but be impacted by god nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

"Is what is pious loved by the gods because it is pious, or is it pious because it is loved by the gods?" - Plato stating the Euthyphro dilemma.

The flaw is both god/s & reality are likely vastly beyond our understanding - see the Kurzgesacht video [The Egg](https://youtu.be/h6fcK_fRYaI) for an illustrative example.

Judaism & Islam insist directly god is unimaginable, divinely incorporeal, & aniconic because any representation inc imagination must tragically fall short. Only Christian philosophy makes a mental toy of god

Comment: A good point about my question. Some might argue that god and good, although differing by an "o" might be one at the same. But then, if the quality of goodness is also beyond anyone's understanding, is it not also irrelevant?

Comment: @stuartstevenson: You could take Plato's approach, modelling it on things like perfect circles that can't exist but can be progressively better approximated https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Form_of_the_Good Or treat as a direction to point in, a practice that moves in a direction